# Aligning elements left, center and right in flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

I'm trying to create this top header using flexbox.

[image: header]

Basically I would like to center the `<div class="header-title">` (Institution institution 1) on the line with the 3 other elements you see. (Institutioner, Ledere and Log ud) like you see on the image.

```css
.nav {
    background: #e1e1e1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}
.header-title {
  justify-content: center;
    align-self: center;
    display: flex;
}
.nav ul li.logout {
      margin-left: auto;
}
.nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0px 20px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav mobilenav">
  <div class="header-title">
    Institution institution 1
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/institutions/">Institutioner</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="/leaders/">Ledere</a>
    </li>
    <li class="logout">
      <a class="button-dark" href="/user/logout">Log ud</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[Demo - JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3mvueq29/)

Comment: Not possible with flexbox and your current html structure. Flexbox assumes the elements you are aligning are at the same level (you have the menus nested inside)

Comment: Hi @KevinJantzer thanks for your comment, what would you suggest then?

Comment: If you are open to changing your html, you need to put all the items in your header on the same level in the dom

Comment: @DaniP Sorry I thought a jsfiddle would be kind of the same thing

Comment: No problem a jsfiddle is ok as an adittion if there are a lot of code but always include the relevant part ... will delete my comments

Comment: If you have control over the html, may I suggest that you make three wrapper-divs: one for the left part of the menu, one for your header and one for the logout button. Position those with flexbox, and position the elements within.

Comment: An example with less code https://jsfiddle.net/3mvueq29/2/

Comment: @glaux yes I was thinking about that as well I will try that. I could also make a dirty solution with some posititon absolute and line-height I guess but that doesnt seem right.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Use nested flex containers and `flex-grow: 1`.

This allows you to create three equal-width sections on the nav bar.

Then each section becomes a (nested) flex container which allows you to vertically and horizontally align the links using flex properties.

Now the left and right items are pinned to the edges of the container and the middle item is perfectly centered (even though the left and right items are different widths).

```css
.nav {
  display: flex;
  height: 50px;      /* optional; just for demo */
  background: white;
}

.links {
  flex: 1;          /* shorthand for: flex-grow: 1, flex-shrink: 1, flex-basis: 0 */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px dashed red;
}

.header-title {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px dashed red;
}

.logout {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px dashed red;
}

.links a {
  margin: 0 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav mobilenav">

  <div class="links">
    <a href="/institutions/">Institutioner</a>
    <a href="/leaders/">Ledere</a>
  </div>

  <div class="header-title">Institution institution 1</div>

  <div class="logout"><a class="button-dark" href="/user/logout">Log ud</a></div>

</div>
```

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3mvueq29/3/)

Comment: Is it possible to prevent Logout element being wrapped into two lines when the window goes very small and instead cut the space from the header-title? (and when the window is wide enough, keeping header-title perfectly centered )

Comment: I was trying for hours to get my responsive Tailwind CSS navbar to work correctly, until I found your solution. It works wonders to push the logo to the left, center the menu items and utility buttons within a div to the right. Only thing I had to change was `align-items: center` to `align-self: flex-start` to keep them to the top. Bravo. Well done!.

Comment: This might be what Marcel was saying, but this only allows 1/3 of the screen for each part, even if the others are very small.  The CSS grid solutions seem better these days, since they don't have that problem.

Answer (score 9):

Use `justify-content: space-between;` like this:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>A</div>
  <div>B</div>
  <div>C</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This only centers B in the container if A and C have the same width.

Answer (score 2):

Css grid will do this better than flexbox.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  align-items: center;
}
button {
  display: inline-block;
}
.short-content {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="long-content">
    This has content that is fairly long
  </div>
  <button>CTA Button</button>
  <div class="short-content">
    Small Text
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Flex solution that aligns the right and left containers while centering the middle container correctly.

```css
.header-box {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    padding-top: 50px;
    
}
.left-header, .center-header, .right-header {
    flex: 100px; /* adjust width if needed */
}
.header-box div:nth-of-type(1) {
    text-align: left;
}
.header-box div:nth-of-type(2) {
    align-self: center;
    text-align: center;
}
.header-box div:nth-of-type(3) {
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-box">
  <div class="left-header">Left<br>header<br>content</div>
  <div class="center-header">Center<br>header<br>content</div>
  <div class="right-header">Right<br>header<br>content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are open to changing your html, you need to put all the items in your header on the same level in the DOM.

### Here's a working example

```css
.nav {
  background: #e1e1e1;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 60px;
}

.nav > div {
  min-width: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.header-title {
  flex-basis: 80%;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav div a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav mobilenav">

  <div><a href="/institutions/">Institutioner</a></div>

  <div><a href="/leaders/">Ledere</a></div>

  <div class="header-title">
    Institution institution 1
  </div>

  <div class="logout">
    <a class="button-dark" href="/user/logout">Log ud</a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: The problem with this method is that the middle item is not centered in the container. The left and right items are different widths, which results in uneven balance of space. In this case, the middle item is aligned center-right. Here's an illustration: https://jsfiddle.net/92etgd7u/

Comment: Yes I saw that :( The answer below seems like the right solution :) but hey