# angular material flex center and right align

Tags: css, angular, flexbox

I'm using angular flexbox to create a footer.
In the center I have some info and on the right side I have a logo.
Now the info should be centered along the entire page, and the logo should be aligned to the right.
So far this is working, but the info is centered inside it's own container and not along the entire div.
How can I solve this with flexbox? (no position abolute solutions please, just flex)

```
<footer fxLayout="row"
fxLayoutAlign="space-between center">
<div class="info" fxFlex>
  <section>
    <span>Straatlaan 48 | 3500 Hasselt</span>
    <span>011 / 58 96 47</span>
    <span>0487 96 54 18</span>
  </section>
  <section>
    <span>KBC BE36 0014 7993 8372</span>
    <span>BTW 123.423.312</span>
    <span><a routerLink="/">Algemene voorwaarden</a></span>
    <span><a routerLink="/">Privacy</a></span>
  </section>
</div>
<div class="logo">
 <img src="assets/img/logo-footer.png"
    alt="">
</div>
</footer>
```

Info is centerd inside it's own div, not centered along the entire width:
[image]

Comment: did you tried `align='left'` ?

Comment: where do you suggest I use this? I don't think align is a valid html5 tag

Comment: in your css file or add the `style="align='left';"` to your html

Comment: but that's not even valid css, and I don't need to align anything to the left?

Comment: I want the info, adres etc, to be centered, and the logo is in the correct location

Comment: @Michael_B I found that particular answer however I could not find solution suitable for my problem

Comment: @Ruben `align` is an angular material property which will can align material tags.

Comment: @NasiruddinSaiyed I can't find this, can you add a link to the docs?

Comment: I suggest, Use the custom classes and follow the below links:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43211390/aligning-elements-left-center-and-right-in-flexbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div>B</div>
  <div>C</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I got it to work by wrapping it in a div

```
<div fxFlexAlign="end">
   <button>...</button>
</div>
```