# Centering grid child regardless of siblings width

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a CSS grid container with 3 children, all with a different width. I want the 2 side children to be at the 2 sides of the container and the middle child to be at the center.

I tried setting the first one to `justify-self: start`, the middle one to `justify-self: center;`, and the last one to `justify-self: end;`, but it doesn't get centered, it just divides the space evenly.

```css
.container {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
 height: 100px;
}
.first {
 justify-self: start;
 background-color: red;
 width: 50px;
}
.middle {
 justify-self: center;
 background-color: green;
 width: 70px;
}
.last {
 justify-self: end;
 background-color: blue;
 width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first"></div>
  <div class="middle">Center me</div>
  <div class="last"></div>
</div>
```

Am I'm missing something? Is this not possible?

Comment: So you want unequal gaps between the columns?

Comment: Yes, I want it to be centered even if it means unequal gaps

Comment: here is with flexbox: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55393886/8620333 (with grid, simply replace auto by 1fr)

Comment: The problem is that the rendering engine doesn't know what to align the center column _to_. There's no concept of "center" with respect to the sibling elements, only to the parent.

Comment: That's exactly what I want, I want it to be centered in respect to the parent and ignore the fact that this will make it have unequal gaps between the siblings

Comment: flexbox solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43211390/

Answer (score 1):

You could use the grid for the outer elements and center the middle one using absolute position and transforms like so:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  height: 100px;
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
}
.first {
  justify-self: start;
  background-color: red;
  width: 50px;
}
.middle {
  background-color: green;
  width: 70px;
  position:absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  height:100%;
}
.last {
  justify-self: end;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first"></div>
  <div class="middle">Center me</div>
  <div class="last"></div>
</div>
```

But be aware that elements could overlap using this method.

Answer (score 1):

Use `1fr` instead of `auto` since you are explicitly defining the width of your elements

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  height: 100px;
  /* The center */
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  background: linear-gradient(black, black) bottom center/5px 5px no-repeat;
}

.first {
  justify-self: start;
  background-color: red;
  width: 50px;
}

.middle {
  justify-self: center;
  background-color: green;
  width: 70px;
}

.last {
  justify-self: end;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first"></div>
  <div class="middle">Center me</div>
  <div class="last"></div>
</div>
```