# Align items to the left and right in React Native

Tags: css, react-native

How do you align items to the left and the right in React Native?

Whatever combination of flexbox properties I try, the two sets of text are stuck next to each other like this:

[image]

How do you make it so "Sign In" is on the right side of the screen and Repositories on the left?

Here is my code:

```
import { View, StyleSheet, Text, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import { Link } from "react-router-native";

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    paddingLeft: 10,
    paddingBottom: 20,
    backgroundColor: 'grey',
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 20,
    color: 'white',
    fontWeight: 'bold'
  },
  linkText: {
    color: 'white',
  },
  nesteddivleft: {
    flex: 1,          
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "flex-start",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  nesteddivright: {
    flex: 1,
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "flex-end",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  scrollbar: {
display: 'flex',
justifyContent: 'space-between'
  }
});

const AppBar = () => {
  return <><View style={styles.container}>
    <ScrollView style="scrollview" horizontal>
    <View style={styles.nesteddivleft}><Link to="/"><Text style={styles.text}>Repositories</Text></Link></View>
    <View style={styles.nesteddivright}><Link to="/signin"><Text style={styles.linkText}>Sign In</Text></Link></View>
    </ScrollView>
    </View>
    </>
};

export default AppBar;
```

App:

```
import Main from './src/components/Main'
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { NativeRouter } from 'react-router-native';


export default function App() {

  return (
<> 
     <NativeRouter>
     <Main/>
     </NativeRouter>
     <StatusBar style="auto" />
</>
  );
}
```

As you can see, I have tried putting justify-content: space-between on the parent div and that does nothing.

I also tried this solution and it has done nothing: [Aligning elements left, center and right in flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43211390/aligning-elements-left-center-and-right-in-flexbox)

Comment: <View styles={{display:'flex', justify-content: 'space-between'}}> 

  <View style={styles.nesteddivleft}>
     <Link to="/">
         <Text style={styles.text}>Repositories</Text>
    </Link>
  </View>

  <View style={styles.nesteddivright}>
    <Link to="/signin">
     <Text style={styles.linkText}>Sign In</Text>
   </Link>
 </View>
</View>

Comment: if you only have 2 items then you can use flex and [`justify-content: space-between`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content#space-between)

Comment: I only have two items and I've used flex and justify-content - space-between and it hasn't done anything...

Comment: are you sure your flex container is 100% width?  If so the you need to show us your html and css (not react) in a [mcve]

Comment: I set the width of the flex container to minWidth: 100% and still the same result.

Comment: Please view the solution that I have posted.

Answer (score 1):

```
    import { View, StyleSheet, Text, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import { Link } from "react-router-native";

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    paddingLeft: 10,
    paddingBottom: 20,
    backgroundColor: 'grey',
    display: "flex",
justifyContent: "space-between",
minWidth: '100%',
flexDirection: "row"
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 20,
    color: 'white',
    fontWeight: 'bold'
  },
  linkText: {
    color: 'white',
  },
  nesteddivleft: {
  },
  nesteddivright: {
  },
  scrollbar: {

  }
});

const AppBar = () => {
  return <><View style={styles.container}>
  
    <View style={styles.nesteddivleft}><Link to="/"><Text style={styles.text}>Repositories</Text></Link></View>
    <View style={styles.nesteddivright}><Link to="/signin"><Text style={styles.linkText}>Sign In</Text></Link></View>
 
    </View>
    </>
};

export default AppBar;
```

Steps to solve issue:

1. Take out the scrollview component.
2. set Display to flex, justify Content to space-between, minWidth to 100% AND flex Direction to Row in parent component.

Not optimal as I need the Scrollview component in there as well, I will need to find a solution that allows me to have that component as a child.